# Writing a YAML file using SnakeYAML

Tags: java, dictionary, yaml, config, snakeyaml

I've been trying to create a method that combines values that I have into a Map that Yaml.load can read. So, for example:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("example.key.abc", "test");
map.put("example.key.def", "another test");
map.put("example.test", "yet another test");
map.put("example2.ex", "ex2");
```

And I want to turn this into a Map that Yaml can read. I've tried putting, for example, abc and def into a map with their values, and then putting that map into maps with other values. I can never seem to get this to work. Also, I want this to be able to work with any key, so just doing the maps manually won't work. This is the output that I would expect to get from the keys above if I could run a Map that was readable with Yaml through the rest of my code:

```
example:
  key:
    abc: test
    def: another test
  test: yet another test
example2:
  ex: ex2
```

I just can't seem to make that method that can combine the Map that I have into a Map that Yaml can understand. Is there an API out there, or is this a just a really easy method to make that I just can't figure out? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

What do you think about [Guavas Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) (expecially the [MapSplitter #withKeyValueSeparator](https://gist.github.com/dtulig/1271761)), in combination with a [mapTransformation](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained) like

```
Maps.transformEntries(fromMap, transformer)
```

so the resulting map, you can give to snakeYaml looks like

```
Map<String,Map<String,Map<String, String>>> =
  ImmutableMap.of("example", ImmutableMap.of("key", ImmutableMap.of("abc", "test")...
```

btw: do you know HOCON from [typesafe-config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#examples-of-hocon), this library supports reading and writing of dot separated (Map formed) configfiles

```
foo.bar=10
foo.baz=12
```

to

```
Config foo = conf.getConfig("foo");
int bar2 = foo.getInt("bar");
```

or

```
int bar1 = conf.getInt("foo.bar");
```